# Failed to load post in post request using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a post http request in Flutter, but i'm receiving this exception:

> E/flutter ( 7566): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)]
>   Unhandled Exception: Exception: Failed to load post E/flutter ( 7566):

My class **RegistrarPage**:

```
final nomeController = new TextEditingController();
  final emailController = new TextEditingController();
  final telefoneController = new TextEditingController();
  final senhaController = new TextEditingController();

  Future<Usuario> registraUsuario() async {
    final response = await http.post('https://cademeupet.net/api/registrar', 
    body: {
      "nome": nomeController.text,
      "email": emailController.text,
      "telefone": telefoneController.text,
      "senha": senhaController.text
    },
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json"
      }
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If server returns an OK response, parse the JSON.]
      debugPrint(response.body);
      return Usuario.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      // If that response was not OK, throw an error.
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }
```

My class **Usuario**:

```
class Usuario {
  final String nome;
  final String email;
  final String senha;
  final String telefone;

  Usuario({this.nome, this.email, this.senha, this.telefone});

  factory Usuario.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Usuario
    (
      nome: json['nome'],
      email: json['email'],
      senha: json['senha'],
      telefone: json['telefone']
    );
  }

  Map toMap() {
    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    map["nome"] = nome;
    map["email"] = email;
    map["senha"] = senha;
    map["telefone"] = telefone;
    return map;
  }
}
```

The api is working because i tested it in postman and everything works well but in flutter i'm receiving this exception

Comment: Your own code is throwing that exception in the `else`. What's the non-200 status code that you are getting?

Comment: try and tell what errorcode you get -----  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If server returns an OK response, parse the JSON.]
      debugPrint(response.body);
      return Usuario.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      // If that response was not OK, throw an error.
      throw Exception('Failed to load post with http code :' + response.statusCode.toString());
    }